# How to get object of Pop-up screen that blocks the main screen using firepath in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am writing an automation script in Java in selenium webdriver. When I try to logoff my main window screen I am getting a pop-up window that does not allow me to go to the main screen unless I click some option "Leave page" or "Stay on page" . Can I get the script to close this screen and logoff the main application.Firepath does not work for this as well. I am a beginner trying to learn automation.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some of your code to the question would be useful...

Here is a wild guess, assuming that you have a `WebDriver driver` instance:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();  // Leave Page
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss(); // Stay on page
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these first:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();  // to leave page
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();  // to accept page
```

if doesn't work, then you can use Robot class to press Enter or any Key like -

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.setAutoDelay(3000);

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Only thing you've to notice - which button the default cursor or which one is highlighted, Robot will perform action on the highlighted object only, from there you can press tab to go anywhere else.
Hope this helps.